# Lazy loading a module when opening a modal

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to lazy load a module to use inside a modal. How can I achieve that?

In other words, the modal is the container and the module is the content that need to be lazy loaded.

I'm using angular 8 and at this point is doesn't seem a good idea to upgrade the version.

I'll leave a test case for a better understanding:

Imagine a module with 3 components: login, register and recover password. I might want to go directly to any of them. And, using the application, I might not go there at all, so it doesn't need to be loaded. I can I get a solution that let's me do that? For now, I have a route to the modal, another one inside (as a child) to the module and I use a router to navigate between the components. But when I close the modal at, let's say, recover password, and after a while, I want to reopen it at login, it executes recover before navigating.

Comment: I think you probably mean loading a component in your modal.. that is very possible..

Comment: That is a mistake I would want to have made, for sure, but no. I meant a module. :/

Comment: But if you can show me how to do it with a component, I may have a way to include it in my solution. Just throw an answer, please. :) @MikeOne

Comment: You can only lazy load module with the Angular router but Angular 9 has lazy loaded components. https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to achieve really. Techincally you could put a router-outlet in you modal, and lazy load a module for that specific (named?) outlet. But the question remains, what do you actually want?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain in better. Imagine a module with 3 components: login, register and recover password. I might want to go directly to any of them. And, using the application, I might not go there at all, so it doesn't need to be loaded. I can I get a solution that let's me do that? For now, I have a route to the modal, another one inside (as a child) to the module and I use a router to navigate between the components. But when I close the modal at, let's say, recover password, and after a while, I want to reopen it at login, it executes recover before navigating.

Comment: @MikeOne does this help?

Comment: Right. I mean, I applaud the quest for better performance, however, these modules don’t sound like they are huge.. so is it worth even trying to get them lazy-loaded in the first place? The costs of the added complexity might not offset any performance gain..

Comment: Well... I might say you have a very valid point, there. The think is I have 2 other modules, which are quite heavier than this one in which I need to do same. If there is some other way that does not involve lazy loading, I might be willing to discuss it anyway.